# C++: Do I need GCC and GDB with the same version to debug

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, gdb

I am developing in C++ on Windows with minGW. I have debugging problems at the moment.

I must use an old version of GCC (4.4).
So I was just wondering if it is possible to compile with this old GCC and debug with a new GDB?

What is the link between the two of them?

(Any pointers regarding debugger crashes would be greatly appreciated too!
I just know that I need to be sure to use debug DLLs)

Comment: Why should there be a link between one and the other? What is your debugging problem? Which dlls you mean by debug dlls. You don't need to have debugging symbols anywhere, it will just be harder to debug...

Comment: Actually tried in the meantime with GDB from the last minGW version and it works properly. I just wanted to understand what is the link between them. Regarding debug DLLs I thought it was mandatory to use them in debug. I am learning quite everything on my own... And still so much to learn. So now I need to have a look at "debugging symbols"! Thanks for your help.

Comment: the only link is the format of the debugger information which is standardised so the new gdb comes with additional capabilities / features/ bug fixes to the previous version. Having said that they are two different programs nearly like vim and emacs in order to understand each other they both need to use the same standard but they are independent (in text editing programs the standard is UTF or other encoding, in compiler its debugger info format for gcc its dwarf afaik).

Comment: Thanks for the details regarding the internal behavior of GDB. I didn't think there were a standard format for the debug info. I don't regret posting this question!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GDB and GCC are separate programs -- separate source bases (with a bit of shared code, though not much), generally separate maintainers, different release schedules, and different version numbers.  They do share a bit of culture and of course there is some coordination.

GDB is reasonably good about backward compatibility.  It even keeps workarounds for bugs in debuginfo emitted by older versions of GCC and sometimes other compilers.  What this means is that you can usually upgrade GDB while keeping the same GCC version.

The reverse, though, is not always the case.  Sometimes a new version of GCC emits debug info that an older GDB cannot understand.  In this situation you must upgrade GDB as well.  In some limited situations you can pass a compatibility flag to GCC to ask for downgraded debug info, but this isn't always possible.  And, since it is simple to upgrade GDB, you might as well.

Comment: Thanks for this general answer. I have a much better understanding of the "link" between those programs. It's good to know that GDB tries to keep backward compatibility. At this point I don't need to stick to an old GDB release. So hopefully I won't experience your last point.

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory for GCC and gdb to be of same version. You can debug your executable with the version of gdb you have in your hand.                              Gdb a.out

Comment: Tried in the meantime and it works! (Actually I use GDB thru an IDE). Thanks!