# How to debug C++-Program which triggers internal bug in gdb?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb

In one of my C++-projects I found an issue related to a linked library which results in a segfault directly after starting the compiled executable. I tried to dive into the issue using gdb, but it fails with the output:

```
../../gdb/dwarf2/read.c:1857: internal-error: bool dwarf2_per_objfile::symtab_set_p(const dwarf2_per_cu_data*) const: Assertion `per_cu->index < this->m_symtabs.size ()' failed.
```

After it is an internal error I am not able to do much (except reporting it), but I still would like to be able to debug the program itself. Which options do I have for that?

- Use of a different debugger than gdb?
- Manual update to a newer version of gdb (currently on 10.1)?
- Somehow catch the segfault before it is damaging the debugger?
- ?

Comment: Yes, in your situation I would try first to upgrade GDB to latest version. And then, if still crashing, try with LLDB. Good luck.

Comment: Maybe you can try to enable *Address Sanitizer*. Probably that the sanitizer will catch the error, and maybe it is give you an meaningful report. Maybe GDB will not crash in that situation.

Comment: Another possible solution: swap compiler. I was using clang and got this error. swapping to gcc did the job. Otherwise switch to older compilers, as [newer compilers can cause problems for gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29812294/8658157).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely this is already fixed gdb bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=28160. It has Target Milestone 11.1, so update to a latest version of gdb which is 11.1 now. It should be fixed in that version.